# Redirecionar para uma pagina através de um post

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, post

Pessoal precisava fazer o seguinte tenho uma pagina feita em html puro e nela tenho uma área onde o usuário pode colocar seu e-mail e pedir pra cadastra-lo. Ai queria pegar este e-mail do inoput text e no post direcionar para outra página onde pego a string recebida e a trato no controller. porém não estou tendo sucesso ao incluir o valor do input na minha url.

```html
<form>
    <section class="call-to-action text-white text-center">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
                    <h2 class="mb-4">Quer receber as melhores ofertas dos nossos parceiros? Cadastre-se abaixo!</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7 mx-auto">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-9 mb-2 mb-md-0">
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Digite seu melhor email...">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit" id="enviar" formmethod="post" formaction="../Home/GetEmail/?email=document.getElementById('email').value" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar!</button>
         
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

porem ao redirecionar fica assim:

**http://localhost:64073/Home/GetEmail/?email=document.getElementById(%27email%27).value**

talvez minha forma de concatenar esteja errada.
Algum id~eia como resolver isso?

Comment: Vê se adicionando o atributo `action="../Home/GetEmail/` na sua `tag form` resolve o seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na verdade era apenas um forma de concatenar a string no formaction :\

formaction="../Home/GetEmail/?email=document.getElementById('email').value"

ele passa na minha url:
/Home/GetEmail/?email=document.getElementById(%27email%27).value

Mas o no controller consegue recuperar o e-mail e ai deu certo!

```html
        public ActionResult GetEmail(string email)
        {
            EmailRegister emailregister = new EmailRegister();

            if (email != "" && email != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    emailregister.Email = email;
                    emailregister.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now;

                    _emailregisterRepository.InsertEmailRegister(emailregister);
                    _emailregisterRepository.Save();

                    TempData["Message"] = "E-mail cadastrado com sucesso!";

                }
                catch (DataException ex)
                {
                    TempData["Error"] = "Não foi possível salvar as alterações. Tente de novo, e se o problema persistir consulte o administrador do sistema. Erro: " + ex.Message;
                }

            }


            return View("GetEmail");
        }
```